# Sort functions in a module

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell module with about 50 functions but they are not sorted in alphabetic order :

```
function CountUsers
{
    code
}

function TestAccess
{
    code
}

function PingServer
{
    code
}
```

I would like to sort them by alphabetic order such as :

```
function CountUsers
{
    code
}

function PingServer
{
    code
}

function TestAccess
{
    code
}
```

I can't find a way to do that, any help appreciated.

Comment: You could write a script to parse for each of the functions, then sort them by function name and output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this [using a regex](http://function%20CountUsers%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20code%20%7D%20function%20PingServer%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20code%20%7D%20function%20TestAccess%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20code%20%7D) where you capture the *whole function* and the *name of the function:* 
`(?s)(function (.*?){[^}]*})`Now you can sort the captures using the name and print the whole function:

```
$x = @'
function CountUsers
{
    code
}

function TestAccess
{
    code
}

function PingServer
{
    code
}

'@

$regex = '(?s)(function (.*?){[^}]*})'    
[regex]::Matches($x, $regex) | sort { $_.Groups[2].Value } | % { $_.Groups[0].Value }
```

*Output*:

```
function CountUsers
{
    code
}
function PingServer
{
    code
}
function TestAccess
{
    code
}
```

Comment: Your regex example doesn't work when there are nested code blocks using { }.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit like Martin Brandl's answer, but this:

- Works even if there are nested code blocks, an issue mentioned in the other answer's comments by 'New Guy'
- Sorts top-level functions, classes, *and* enums
- Separates each function/class/enum by a blank line
- Works with PowerShell's case-insensitivity (`Function` vs `function` etc.)

RegEx explanation: https://regex101.com/r/avNDhV/1

Top-level code that's not a function, class, or enum is not kept; compare input/output line counts for a quick sanity check.

```
$pattern = '(?i)(?:function|class|enum) [^{]+{(?>{(?<c>)|[^{}]+|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}'

([regex]::Matches($input, $pattern) | Sort).ForEach({ $_.Value }) -join "`n`n"
```

*Input*

```
function Foo
{
    # code
}

function Bar
{
    # code
}
```

*Output*

```
function Bar
{
    # code
}

function Foo
{
    # code
}
```